# C# Open a form from another form, which is located in a different project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, multiple-projects

I have two different projects, `DriverSide` and `LogInForm`. In both of them is a form, in `DriverSide` the form `Form1` will be executed on the start of the application and in `LogInForm` the important form is the `UserOnTrip` form. On `Form1` is a button and with it´s click event i want to open the `UserOnTrip` form, but i dont know how to handle it because the forms are on different projects.

---

This is my button click method:

```
private void _btnAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        LogInForm._pnlUserOntrip _pnl = new LogInForm._pnlUserOntrip();
        _pnl.Show();
        //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.StartupPath.ToString() + @"\_pnlUserOnTrip.exe");

        LogInForm.LoadingScreen _load = new LogInForm.LoadingScreen();
        _load.Hide();
    }
}
```

And this is the layout of my solution explorer:

[image]

Comment: Please provide us all your code.

Comment: Make your code more readable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions

Comment: all codes in that form sir?

Comment: What are *"User and Driver side"*? 2 different PCs? Then you need some kind of communications between them, probably network communications.

Comment: User side and Driver side are 2 different projects

Comment: @Sinatr I guess he just means two different projects in one solution in VS. I think he just misses out to import a reference from the other namespace to be able to call it´s form.

Comment: @L.Guthardt I have done the 2 project 1 solution but the problem is whenever i call the form it runs in Driver project not in the User ones.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your solution explorer and right click on the project you want to execute. Now click 'Set as start project'. This project gets highlighted then a bit, you should see atleast any difference.

[Have a look at this picture](https://ixquick-proxy.com/do/spg/show_picture.pl?l=deutsch&rais=1&oiu=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeproject.com%2FKB%2Fcs%2F607868%2FSolutionExplorer.jpg&sp=f3d301749622ed8a3ecf1a871e52700a). There are the two different projects: John.Socialclub.Data and John.Socialclub.Desktop. And you dont click on any of those files below, right click on of your projects itself and set them simply as start project.

---

**Updated:**

So i understood it that way, that you execute in the project `DriverSide` the `Form1`. On this form you have a button which shell open the form `UserOnTrip` which is located in the `LogInForm` project.

First of all you want to add a reference to the `DriverSide` project. Go once again to the solution explorer and righ click on `References`. Then click `Add reference`. Then a menu pops up where you select on the left side `projects`. Now there should be your project `LogInForm` listed, you select it with the comboBox and press OK.

Now we are in the `Form1` of `DriverSide`:

In the beginning note that you have to add this `using` reference to use the reference to the `LogInForm`. Add this to the other using references.

```
using LogInForm;

namespace DriverSide
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void _btnAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserOnTrip testWindow = new UserOnTrip();
            testWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

I just copied your button click method `_btnAccept_Click`. Insert this code and you should be fine. You can ignore the constructor `public Form1()`, i just placed it in there that you feel familiar with your code and understand exactly where to place what.